# How can banks make profit from mortgages with interest rate 1.29%?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer

At the current moment HSBC is proposing mortgages with interest rate 1.29% fixed for 5 years for 75% LTV:

https://www.hsbc.co.uk/mortgages/our-rates/#tab-panel-tab_1539213631

I wonder what is the reason for HSBC for proposing such low rates, are they really making profit this way (taking into account inflation)?

I am asking the question because I wonder if there are some hidden risks for those who take such a (5 year fixed) mortgage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The five-year gilt yield is currently 0.30%, and HSBC is paying 0.20% interest on fixed-term savings accounts (and 0.01% on many of its other savings accounts). Mortgage lending is pretty low-risk, and they can certainly make money on the spread between 1.3% and 0.3% or 0.2%. They don’t have to worry about inflation, because what they lose on the money they lend out they gain on their deposits.

Comment: Also there is a £999 fee for the 1.29% option, so it's not a 'real' rate; the rate without the fee is 1.69%.

Comment: "... what they lose on the money they lend out they gain on their deposits" — Could you explain how that works?

Comment: If you have £1 million, and inflation is 3%, then you have lost £30,000 of value in a year. But if you’ve lent out £1 million and you have £1 million in deposits then you have no skin in the game — your debtors will benefit from inflation, but it’s your creditors who suffer the corresponding loss, not you.

Comment: @richardb I thought you pay £999 only once to get this 1.29% option, is not this the case? If so, the real rate will be closer to 1.29%  rather than 1.69%? Or is this not the case?

Comment: @MikeScott many thanks for your answer, and for answering the comment of Flux. This makes sense!

Comment: @aglearner You will be better off paying the fee and taking the lower rate in most cases, yes.

Comment: Lenders make money by the lending multiplier effect, not on the spread.  Depending on the jurisdiction, the multiplier factor can range from a low of 1 to a high of 35.  So for every dollar the lender takes in, he or she may be able to loan up to 35 dollars.  And now you know why we had a loan bubble that burst in 2008 and another one today since regulations have been relaxed, particularly in the US.